# Can't locate object method "default_header" via package "LWP::UserAgent"

Tags: perl, twitter, lwp

I am trying to test Twitter Module of Perl for some work and facing the mentioned subject line while running it. The system where I am running it is AIX and Perl version is 5.8.8

Code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use Net::Twitter::Lite;
use Scalar::Util 'blessed';
use strict;
require LWP::UserAgent;
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
$ua->timeout(10);
$ua->env_proxy;


my $consumer_key = "ck";
my $consumer_secret = "cs";
my $access_key = "ak";
my $access_secret = "as";


my $nt = Net::Twitter::Lite->new(
    consumer_key        => $consumer_key,
    consumer_secret     => $consumer_secret,
    access_token        => $access_key,
    access_token_secret => $access_secret,
);

$nt->update("Status Update from Perl!");
```

Error:

```
Can't locate object method "default_header" via package "LWP::UserAgent"
   at /ts/vb/perl5/lib/perl5/Net/Twitter/Lite.pm line 104.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Net::Twitter::Lite is probably using a feature that that was added to LWP::UserAgent in a later version than the one you have installed. Upgrade LWP::UserAgent.

Comment: Thanks ikegami .. this is my first day with Perl (Edited).. we upgrade through CPAN right... like CPAN LWP::UserAgent

Comment: cpan LWP::UserAgent gave me the error like "Running make install make test had returned bad status, won't install without force" While cpanm LWP::UserAgent gave the following error   "! Failed to unpack libwww-perl-6.05.tar.gz: no directory   ! Failed to fetch distribution libwww-perl-6.05". I think I am dealing with a far difficult problem here.

Comment: `cpan`...what error did you actually get? That's just reporting that you got an error earlier on.

Comment: Sorry the Error was *Running make install make test had returned bad status, won't install without force* So i started CPAN commond line tool and did *force install LWP::UserAgent* . the problem is gone for now but not sure for how much time. Thank a ton for the answer above.

Comment: Again, that's not the actual error message. That's just a telling you there was an an error on. `force install` was a really really bad idea. Now you have a module that may not even work properly installed.

Comment: If you want to find out what the problem was, enter these at the `cpan` prompt: `force get LWP::UserAgent`, `force make LWP::UserAgent` and `force test LWP::UserAgent`. (Doing step by step and using `force` makes sure it does it even though you have the lastest version installed.) Making this a new question would be simpler.